# Htaccess rewrite so many times if I have broken links or css in page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I have a simple MVC PHP application. In this application all URL calls rewrite to the index.php file, in root of application.
To do this I wrote the following lines in htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Rewrite works correctly unless in the HTML code is a broken link to an image, js or css!
In this case htaccess rewrite to index.php again, like refreshing page. For example If I have a 10-20 broken links htaccess rewrite 10-20 times same index.php page!

How can I prevent this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Live long and prosper. :)